# How to write urls and views when a OneToOne field is a lookup field?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a situation where I'm storing the user profile in a different django model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Using default Model ViewSet I get the following URL to GET/UPDATE a particular instance of the profile

`/api/profile/user`

Now, since I'm using token authentication, the client only has a token and is not aware of the user. How can a write a URL of the following form

`/api/profile`

This seems more natural to me as a user can have only one `Profile` object and hence his token should be sufficient to do all the operations in his API calls.

Writing custom views is one option but is there any way I can leverage `DRF` to achieve the same with minimal manual implementation?

Answer (score 0):

#### Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

#### Your View:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class GetToken(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        context = {
            "token": unicode(token[0]),
        }
        return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)



class UsedToken(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, format=None): 
        # You are using TokenAuthentication and if header include your token then user access your stuff.. 
        # Header: Authorization: 'Token yourtoken'  
        context = {}
        return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```